# How to dynamically toggle the `resizable` boolean in the jQuery UI Layout plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

## Problem

---

I am using the jQuery UI Layout plugin ([layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm)) in my web application.

Using 2 panels only (`center` and `east`), I need to dynamically disable the resizable option of the layout.

```js
function InitializeLayout(sElement) {
    var oOptions = {
        closable:               false,
        resizable:              true,
        slidable:               false,
        east__livePaneResizing: true,
        east__maxSize:          672,
        east__minSize:          250,
        east__onresize_end:     function() {
            // GetOverlaySizes();
            // SetOverlaySizes();
            // SetPaperSizes();
        },
        east__size:             250
    };
    oLayout = $(sElement).layout(oOptions);
    oLayout.options.east.resizable = false;
    console.log(oLayout.options);
}
```

This doesn't work, even though the `resizable` option is set to `false` on the console.

## Questions

---

1. How do I dynamically disable/enable the `resizable` option ?
2. This has nothing to do with my problem, but why does enabling the live pane resizing make Mozilla Firefox (20.0) so slow ?

Thanks,

## Solution

---

```js
oLayout.disableResizable("east");
oLayout.enableResizable("east");
```

Thanks to @dwaddell.

Comment: The Layout plugin can be rather confusing, do you have a jsFiddle? I have dynamically changed other settings by also setting *.state.east.* along with *.options.east.*.

Comment: [jsfiddle.net/bEeZY/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bEeZY/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to do, after the init:

```
oLayout.disableResizable('east');
```

Hope that helps.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/YE2CQ/

Comment: Thanks it works. You seem to be very capable regarding this plugin and I guess you basically read the sources to find this method. Did you by any chance noticed a method which would reset the layout back to my `oOptions` settings (or at least a way to manually set sizes for my panels) ?

Comment: where did you find about disableResizable method?  gone through all their documentation...unable to find it..

Comment: @rahulmaindargi I found it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/jquery-ui-layout/disableResizable/jquery-ui-layout/SWrs3PfoL9g/ucFdTppTkS4J

Comment: @MathieuMarques You can manually size panes by calling oLayout.sizePane('east', 300);

Comment: @dwaddell That'll do it. Thanks for your help.